# What is significance of `NM_OPER_ON_VIEW: PChar = 'OnView'` as constant declaration?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Recently I have started working of one product which has been developed in `delphi 5`.
While going through the code I stuck on one declaration in for `constants` which is as follows:

```
const
  NM_OPER_ON_VIEW: PChar = 'OnView';
```

This type of notation is very new for me.

Can any one tell me the significance of this type of notations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a [typed constant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declared_Constants#Typed_Constants).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [typed constant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Typed_Constants). From the documentation:

> Typed constants, unlike [true constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#True_Constants), can hold values of array, record, procedural, and pointer types. Typed constants cannot occur in constant expressions.
>
> Declare a typed constant like this:
>
> ```
> const identifier: type = value
> ```
>
> where identifier is any valid identifier, type is any type except files and variants, and value is an expression of type. For example,
>
> ```
> const Max: Integer = 100;
> ```
>
> In most cases, value must be a constant expression; but if type is an array, record, procedural, or pointer type, special rules apply.
>
> ....

I would add to that the fact that, unlike true constants, it is possible to take the address of a typed constant.

True constants are often preferable to typed constants because true constants can be used in constant expressions and evaluated by the compiler. Generally, if it is possible to use a true constant, one should do so.

Typed constants must be used if your constant is a more complex type like an array or a record. And then the downside is that the compiler cannot evaluate the constant and instead the value is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks David for clearing my Idea regarding the type Constant.